# What does MyApp::Application.initialize! calling?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, initialization

I am trying to figure out the initialization of rails 3. And i know that every application will calling the following function in environment.rb to initialize the whole app:

MyApp::Application.initialize!

From it we should expect that initialize! is a class method of Rails::Application. But after i red the source code, i found that instead initialize! is an instance method which is actually called:

```
def initialize!(group=:default) #:nodoc:
  raise "Application has been already initialized." if @initialized
  run_initializers(group, self)
  @initialized = true
  self
end
```

So why is the instance method called although we expect a class method? Is there some trick like method delegation or else?

Comment: Maybe this can help as I was searching for a similar question to where that initialize! method is. http://climber2002.github.io/blog/2014/08/26/digging-rails-how-rails-initializes-itself-part-2/ Go back to part one if you have questions on what application is now instead of Application class. The nice listings only relating to the parts of interest are great. See how an instance of your Rails MyApp is now using an instance variable and we may send it to any method in our path. Thanks for your question as it is a good question and it's odd that there is only one answer after all this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. there is a little trick delegation. if you look at file `lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb` in `railties` gem you will see following code that delegates to instance.

```
def method_missing(*args, &block)
  instance.send(*args, &block)
end
```

in case you are not aware of method_missing hook, you can read up more about it here: http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_method_missing.html

Comment: Thanks!I thought before that this calling was delegated to `Rails.initialize!` which just contained one line `application.initialize!` and it made sense. And i add some debug print but found that Rails.initialize! was never called during the initialization process. I missed the `method_missing` guy. So there is another question: why does `Rails.initialize!` exist?

Comment: That code has been there for couple years, so I would assume initially it used to call Rails.initialize! for initialization but at some point community implemented initialization through APP namespace and stopped using that methods. I dont think it is used anywhere. maybe yiu should submit a ticket to rails to deprecate it?